# making a markdown header notation via regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to build a personal markdown editor. Inspired a lot by source-code of the [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs) library I have almost accomplished the task, but some of the codes strangely just don't work as expected. The following part regarding the definition of a header is one of them that has put me in trouble for some days:

`.replace(/^(#)[ \t]*(.+?)[ \t]*\n/gm,"<h1>$2<h1>");`

the regex seems fine when tested in [an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/WzvBe0/1). Any clue why it doesn't work as expected? Is it a browser version issue (*I'm using FF 36.0.1 right now*)?

**EDIT**. This is a minimal example that produces the problem
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="result" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; float:left; border:1px solid #555555;">Result</div>
    <button type="button"  onclick="compile();">Compile !</button>
    <div id="source" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; border:1px solid #555555;" contenteditable="true">Enter Code ...</div>    

        <script>
        var sourceContent, resultContent;
        function compile(){
            sourceContent=document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
            resultContent=sourceContent.replace(/^(#)[ \t]*(.+?)[ \t]*\n+/gm,"<h1>$1</h1>");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=resultContent;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


<!--
tested with:

#title 1
ok
# title 2
ok
#  title 3 #
ok
-->
```

`

Comment: I can't get it to work on regex101, can you post a sample of an example input?

Comment: It [works...](https://regex101.com/r/FD03AC/1)

Comment: Yes, it is working. But You can also use ^(\#+)((\w+)\s+) pattern here https://regex101.com/r/E4CnrM/1

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasAyoub, added the link to a working example in regex101, actually I didn't know regex has the ability to share links for exampe, your example shows me it is possible, thanks :)

Comment: Are you aware that the current version of FF is 50.0.2 ?

Comment: @Kumar, thanks for the code, but although both the provided codes work in regex101 both fail to work on my browser (although your code doesn't allow spaces in the header but that should be simply targetted to do so), if my memories could help I think I have read somewhere that maybe some codes like `(.+?)` are somewhat problematic, but you code is not like that, maybe the problem is with my browser?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub, yes but thanks for reminding me, my working space is not so updated, but if you think that would be the reason for problem I will try first to update the whole working system

Comment: So if the problem is due to the browser let me know to delete my question, or better, give an answer that works on a broader range of browsers and I will be glad to accept it

Comment: You should include a bit more information about the *it doesn't work* part. Any error? Message? Or just no matches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with an editable `div`, the `innerHTML` doesn't contain new lines but `<br>`s, and that's why your regex doesn't fit. You can use textareas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="result" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; float:left; border:1px solid #555555;">Result</div>
    <button type="button"  onclick="compile();">Compile !</button>
    <textarea id="source" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; border:1px solid #555555;" contenteditable="true">Enter Code ...</textarea>    

        <script>
        var sourceContent, resultContent;
        function compile(){
            sourceContent=document.getElementById("source").value;
            resultContent=sourceContent.replace(/^(?:#)\s*(.+?)[ \t]*$/gm,"<h1>$1</h1>");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=resultContent;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or adapt your regex a bit:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="result" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; float:left; border:1px solid #555555;">Result</div>
    <button type="button"  onclick="compile();">Compile !</button>
    <div id="source" style="display:inline-block; width:45%; height:85vh; border:1px solid #555555;" contenteditable="true">Enter Code ...</div>    

        <script>
        var sourceContent, resultContent;
        function compile(){
            sourceContent=document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
          console.log(sourceContent);
            resultContent=sourceContent.replace(/(<br>(?: \/)?)?(?:#)\s*(.+?)[ \t]*(<br(?: \/)?>)/gm,"$1<h1>$2</h1>$3");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=resultContent;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it still doesn't work for me ... No error, only doesn't match ... if it is the browser incomopatibity, do you know a more general regex that works with older browsers either?

Comment: I tested the code in that answer and it gives the JS version equal to 1.5, then updated firefox to v. 50.1.0 and strangely the problem persists, the JS version also still equals 1.5. The problem is like it has something to do with the rest of my codes if that line of code is not problematic, but it is not correct either, as if I use the code `.replace(/(#|_)(?=\S)([^\r]*?\S)\1/g,"<h1>$2</h1>")` instead it works fine, though it doesn't do what I was looking for. So the rest of code is correct and the problem is about the regex used. If it helps I live in Linux.

Comment: I'm almost giving up, right now I added your code to the end of my page and surprisingly it worked (*after modifying "<h1>\$1<h1>" as "<h1>\$1</h1>" to be ore specific*)! But then again added the code to the function used for compiling the markdown source and it failed again. The code itself is not wrong as it works with some regex's but not with some others ... and it was not due to the browser and/or JS versions ... Seems quite odd to me ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my week! I wish I could do more than accepting your answer. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @owari you can: it's called a bounty ;)